# Have 1 argument in a list become 4 arguments

Tags: python, list

```
walkSmall = [((32,194,64,64)),((129,194,64,64)) ,((226,194,64,64)),((323,32,64,128)),((420,32,64,128)),((517,32,64,128))]
class player(object):
        def __init__(self,x,yfilename):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        def get_image(self, x, y, width, height, posX, posY, window):
            #grab an image out of a larger spritesheet
            window.blit(self.spritesheet, (posX,posY), (x,y, width, height))
        def draw(self, win):
            if self.left:
                self.get_image(walkSmall[self.walkCount//3], self.x, self.y)
                self.walkCount += 1
```

When I try to execute this code (I obviously left a few things out), I get the error message that the value from the list **walkSmall** is only one argument and 5 are missing. I want to get the value
Ex:

```
walkSmall[5] = (517,32,64,128)
```

And I want the value to be individual, so it fills in for x,y,width,height

Comment: You can unpack the tupl in the call to `get_image` with the `*` operator. i.e. `self.get_image(*walkSmall[self.walkCount//3], self.x, self.y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it individual, very simple is using something like this :

```
walkSmall = [((32,194,64,64)),((129,194,64,64)) ,((226,194,64,64)),((323,32,64,128)),((420,32,64,128)),((517,32,64,128))]

print(walkSmall[5])
print(walkSmall[5][2])
```

or you can make another function that return 4 values :

```
def your_function(array):
    
    # simple code iteration 2D array

    return a, b, c, d

x, y, width, height = your_function(walkSmall)
```